# Send Soap 1.1 request through python Requests or urllib

Tags: python, soap, python-requests, urllib2

I understand the very first reaction of someone who is reading this is to say "Ah this is a duplicate request" but believe me this is not. I have tried all the examples listed in stack-overflow to achieve what i wanted but still failed to do so.

I want to send the following details that I see in SoapUI to a given WSDL either via urllib2 or requests with following settings after failing miserably to get this done through Zeep and Suds

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <slab:PLChecker>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <slab:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <slab:ServiceProviderReferenceNumber>?</slab:ServiceProviderReferenceNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <slab:ServiceNumber>02xxxxxxxx</slab:ServiceNumber>
         </slab:request>
      </slab:PLChecker>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

[This is the SoapUI settings I've used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itj6r.png)

I have tried httpbasic authentication so far but seems like im lost at how to create a soap envelope with correct:

- Encording
- username
- password
- Authentication type : No authentication
- WSS Password type : PasswordText

Any help on this is much appreciated.
This is the code i've been using so far.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import base64
import urllib
import ssl
ssl.match_hostname = lambda cert, hostname: True

import logging

# These two lines enable debugging at httplib level (requests->urllib3->http.client)
# You will see the REQUEST, including HEADERS and DATA, and RESPONSE with HEADERS but without DATA.
# The only thing missing will be the response.body which is not logged.
try:
    import http.client as http_client
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    import httplib as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

# You must initialize logging, otherwise you'll not see debug output.
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True


url="https://commontest/PService.svc?singleWsdl"
# headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
request_headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}

body = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <slab:PLChecker>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <slab:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <slab:ServiceProviderReferenceNumber>?</slab:ServiceProviderReferenceNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <slab:ServiceNumber>?</slab:ServiceNumber>
         </slab:request>
      </slab:PLChecker>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"""

response = requests.post(url,data=body, verify = False, auth = ('user', 'pass'), headers = request_headers)
print response
```